# JS/CSS files will not load when URL forwarding

Tags: php, ssl, ssl-certificate

I built a streaming radio site and put in on Heroku here: https://radiatelaravel-new.herokuapp.com/ (Caution: The sound autoplays).

When I did URL forwarding from his domain to this [link](http://www.radiate.fm) it does not load any of the CSS/JS files.

The error I get in the console is:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR   /css/app.css
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR   /css/visualize.css
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR   app.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR   jquery.min.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR   dat.gui.min.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR   visualize.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR   main.js
```

It is all written using PHP/Laravel and  HTML/CSS/JS . The code for loading my stylesheets and JS files are written like this:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/dat.gui.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/visualize.js') }}"></script>
```

Any ideas/solutions?

Comment: When inspecting the website, it appeared to be working fine. Seems to be an issue on your end?

Comment: this sit works fine: https://radiatelaravel-new.herokuapp.com/ It's this one that I'm having problems with, when I have URL forwarding.  http://www.radiate.fm/

Comment: ended up taking out the asset() function and just used:                           
<link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet"> and did that for everyone and it works fine now.  Weird I've always used the asset function.  Oh well we are good to go.

Comment: Cleaned up the question

Answer (score 0):

`<link href=" css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">`

`<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">`

`<script src="js/app.js"></script>`

`<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="js/dat.gui.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="js/visualize.js"></script>`

whu u dont just do it like this ?